# Is it logically coherent to imagine a person who has no prior conception of the world?

Tags: epistemology, hume

I'm working my way through *An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding*, and I've come to realize there's a specific problem I've had with several philosophers' writings: they tend to assume as part of their evidence the existence of a type of person that is not *necessarily* possible to exist.

Here's the part that stuck with me from Hume, emph mine:

> **Suppose a person, though endowed with the strongest faculties of reason and reflection, to be brought on a sudden into this world**; he would, indeed, immediately observe a continual succession of objects, and one event following another; but he would not be able to discover any thing farther. He would not, at first, by any reasoning, be able to reach the idea of cause and effect; since the particular powers, by which all natural operations are performed, never appear to the senses; nor is it reasonable to conclude, merely because of one event, in one instance, precedes another, that therefore the one is the cause, the other the effect.
>
> *V.I, Sceptical Solution of these Doubts*

Much of Hume's argument in this section relies on the assumption that "a human who has no prior conceptions of the world" is a reasonable thing to hypothesize exists at all. If that assumption isn't true for any reason, then the argument as written doesn't hold. And as far as I can tell, Hume offers no a priori reason to believe that we can safely assume such a person exists.

To my understanding, Hume is building up to this assumption constructively. It is possible to conceive of someone who has never encountered fire, or any other specific object or concept. Proceeding to erase bits of experience from someone's mind, we can guess that at the limit we'd find someone who has *no* experience, knowledge, understanding, or conception of the world. But that doesn't mean someone like that could necessarily exist - it may be safer, for example, to assume there is some minimum amount of information that it is not possible to be born *without*.

Have I misunderstood Hume's argument? Alternatively, is my understanding of this hole complete, or have I made a mistake in my own thinking here?

More generally, I see this kind of argument often from philosophers - imagining a type of person who might not exist, and using that as the logical basis of reasoning. Is this a commonplace argument? How well accepted is it in academic philosophy?

---

(For what it's worth, this might also be relevant: Hume makes a related limiting argument himself otherwise, and calls it out as a possible exception to his own philosophy, though indicates it is rather trivial:)

> There is, however, one contradictory phenomenon, which may prove, that it is not absolutely impossible for ideas to arise, independent of their correspondent impressions. [...] Let all the different shades of that colour, except that single one [he has not seen] be placed before him, descending gradually from the deepest to the lightest; it is plain, that he will perceive a blank, where that shade is wanting, and will be sensible, that there is a greater distance in that place between the contiguous colours than in any other. Now I ask, whether it be possible for him, from his own imagination, to supply this deficiency[...]? I believe there are few but will be of opinion that he can: And this may serve as a proof, that the simple ideas are not always, in every instance, derived from the correspondent impressions; though this instance is so singular, that it is scarcely worth our observing, and does not merit, that for it alone we should alter our general maxim.
>
> *II: Of the Origin of Ideas*

Comment: Some of this turns on the ambiguity of "necessary" and "possible". Does it mean *logically* possible (non-self-contradictory), *physically* possible, *metaphysically* possible (something in between)? I am not sure that Hume uses this as any more than rhetorical device to stimulate intuition, in which case he does not need much more than logical possibility for his argument. It certainly does not matter much what sorts of humans can physically exist in this world.